# Weights aren't updating on backward pass

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a model that takes a tensor representing the difference between two images and outputs coordinates used to make them more alike. I then calculate the loss as MSE of the created image and the original image, but when I run a backward pass no weights seems to update and the loss remains constant (although not none) throughout all epochs.

Is this because the loss isn't calculated directly on the model output?

When reading other post the **requires_grad** was sometimes responsible for the problem, I've tried with **requires_grad = True** but I'm still a bit unsure if it's used correctly.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10 * 10 * 3, 240)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(240, 240)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(240, 240)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(240, 7)  # [x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g, b]

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
```

```
def array_to_flatten_tensor(array_to_reshape):
    prepared_image = torch.FloatTensor(array_to_reshape)
    prepared_image.requires_grad = True
    prepared_image.retains_grad = True
    return torch.flatten(prepared_image)
```

```
    image = cv2.imread("flower.png")
    image = cv2.resize(image, (10, 10))
    image = torch.FloatTensor(image)
    image.requires_grad = True
    image.retains_grad = True

    image = torch.flatten(image)

    for image_pass in range(1000):
        running_loss = 0
        # Create empty image
        drawn_image = array_to_png_test.generate_empty_RGB_array(10, 10)

        for _ in range(10):

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Pass (image - net drawn) image to net
            difference_array = image - array_to_flatten_tensor(drawn_image)

            output = net_to_train(difference_array)

            # Converts the output to two points and colour
            point_1 = (float(output[0]), 0, float(output[1]))
            point_2 = (float(output[2]), float(output[3]))
            colour = round(max(float(output[4]), 0)), round(max(float(output[5]), 0)), round(max(float(output[6]), 0))

            point_1, point_2 = sorted([point_1, point_2])

            # Draws a line to the empty image
            drawn_image = array_to_png_test.draw_line(point_1, point_2, colour, drawn_image)

            # Calculate loss as mean square difference of image and drawn image
            drawn_image_tensor = array_to_flatten_tensor(drawn_image)

            current_loss = criterion(drawn_image_tensor, image)

            running_loss += float(current_loss)

            current_loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()

        print("epoch " + str(image_pass) + " : " + str(running_loss / 250))
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
net = Net()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.1, betas=(0.9, 0.999))

training(optimizer, criterion, net)
```

Comment: where do you instantiate your optimizer?

Comment: I added the instantiation to the post, I just instantiate it normally

Comment: Try calling net.train()

Comment: i think your lr is quite high. i would try to decrease it.
Try to print the gradients after each backward call to to make sure your gradients or ok.